# Child XML elements are not moving using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am in need to move `<sub>`, `<sup>` elements as shown in the output. I could able to move the `<sup>` element. The child elements are not moving. I am also in need to rename the element as `<msub>` and `<msup>` accordingly. If I run XSLT twice, I could able to get the Output. But I dont want to do that. Kindly correct me where I made mistake. I should use XSLT1.0

Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <math display="block">
        <mfenced>
            <mrow>
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>v</mi>
                        <sub>
                            <mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow>
                        </sub>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>v</mi>
                        <sub>
                            <mrow><mi>d</mi></mrow>
                        </sub>
                    </mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </mrow>
        </mfenced>
        <sup><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></sup>
    </math>
</chapter>
```

Sample XSLT tried:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" exclude-result-prefixes="m">

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::*/following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub"></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="self::*/following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sup"></xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="self::*/following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:subsup"></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:sub">
<msub>
<xsl:copy-of select="self::*/preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</msub>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="m:subsup">
<msubsup>
<xsl:copy-of select="self::*/preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</msubsup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m:sup">
<msup>
<xsl:copy-of select="self::*/preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</msup>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<math display="block">
<msup>
    <mfenced>
        <mrow>
            <mfrac>
                <mrow>
                    <msub><mi>v</mi><mrow><mi>n</mi></mrow></msub>
                </mrow>
                <mrow>
                    <msub><mi>v</mi><mrow><mi>d</mi></mrow></msub>
                </mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mrow>
    </mfenced>
    <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow>
</msup>
</math>
</chapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what you're trying to do is

1. for any `sub` or `sup` element, move its previous sibling (if any) inside the element and
2. rename `sub` to `msub` and `sup` to `msup`.

This XSLT should do the trick:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" exclude-result-prefixes="m">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub]">
    <msub>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub/@* | following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub/node()"/>
    </msub>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sup]">
    <msup>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sup/@* | following-sibling::m:sup/node()"/>
    </msup>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:sub | m:sup"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only thing that's not clear to me is what to do this `sub` (`sup`) elements that have no preceding sibling. The code above just ignores them.

Comment: Please edit your answer as: `<xsl:template match="*[following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub]">` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub/@* | following-sibling::*[1]/self::m:sub/node()"/>` and similarly for m:sup also

Answer (score 0):

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  exclude-result-prefixes="m" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:mfenced">
    <msup>
      <mfenced>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </mfenced>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::m:sup/*" />
    </msup>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:mfrac/m:mrow">
    <mrow>
      <msub>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </msub>
    </mrow>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:sub">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:sup" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the provided XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <math display="block">
    <mfenced>
      <mrow>
        <mfrac>
          <mrow>
            <mi>v</mi>
            <sub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>n</mi>
              </mrow>
            </sub>
          </mrow>
          <mrow>
            <mi>v</mi>
            <sub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>d</mi>
              </mrow>
            </sub>
          </mrow>
        </mfrac>
      </mrow>
    </mfenced>
    <sup>
      <mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
      </mrow>
    </sup>
  </math>
</chapter>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <math display="block">
    <msup>
      <mfenced>
        <mrow>
          <mfrac>
            <mrow>
              <msub>
                <mi>v</mi>
                <mrow>
                  <mi>n</mi>
                </mrow>
              </msub>
            </mrow>
            <mrow>
              <msub>
                <mi>v</mi>
                <mrow>
                  <mi>d</mi>
                </mrow>
              </msub>
            </mrow>
          </mfrac>
        </mrow>
      </mfenced>
      <mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
      </mrow>
    </msup>
  </math>
</chapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Siva, you may block original "mi" output by introducing new template:

<xsl:template match="m:mi">
    <xsl:if
      test="not(name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'sub') and not(name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'sup') and not(name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'subsup')">
      <mi>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </mi>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>